# Docker doesn't see $ symbol

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i need to remove my docker images but when i type this:

```
sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images -q)
```

i get the following error:

```
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rmi --help'.
Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]
```

and the same problem with all commands using $( ) syntax like it don't see anything after $

i used this commands like an hour ago and it worked perfectly

i don't even know how to google it...
what's the problem?

Comment: `$()` is unrelated to `docker`. It is a construct from your shell (e.g. `sh` or `bash`) and is called *command substitution*. To debug this, we need the output of `sudo docker images -q`. If there is no output, then the problem is obvious: You try to remove images even though there are none.

Comment: I think i realized that i'm a fool. May this be because i've cleaned my docker manually before?..

Comment: I'm trying to deploy my app on VPS and i have an endless running docker-compose command, so now it drop a lot runtime errors, i thought that cleaning docker files will help me but it's not. Thanks a lot btw!